# Automapper seems to be caching data

Tags: asp.net, caching, automapper

Automapper version, which i am using in project is, AutoMapper, Version=6.0.2.0

When i run this for the first time, there is a record available in person object, which gets mapped to employee object. In the subsequent runs, though person object does not have any data, employee object holds the previously stored data and it appears to be cached data.
how can i get rid of this ?

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
        cfg.CreateMap<Person, Employee>();
});

person pobj = new person();
pobj.FirstName = "Adam";
pobj.LastName = "Smith";
pobj.Address = "some address";
Mapper.CreateMap<Person, Employee>();
Employee emp = Mapper.Map<Employee>(pobj);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what are you expecting to have in emp in your example and what values do you have? Why do you create map twice?

Comment: emp would have the copy of pobj data.  createmap is to be establish a link between 2 objects and map is to copy data from source to destination.  after going through articles, i now guess if the caching happens due to EF. Need to explore in what scenarios EF does this strong caching that even if the record is deleted from the database, it holds the same in EF